# Sync two PostgreSQL databases over two different DataCenters

Tags: postgresql, virtual-machine, replication, high-availability, failover

We have a very sensitive system and need a High-Availability solution.

Right now, we only have one server on a DataCenter which is really bad! Because today the DataCenter had a problem for almost 1 hour! Our customers were really mad at us!

I really need to have a Stand-By Server on another DataCenter for when our main server from DataCenter 1 has problem! And we migrate to Stand-By server when our Main-Server has problem.

And we also need to come back to our Main Server as soon as problem fixed.

The only thing I'm worry about is the data consistency in this scenario. These two Data Bases must be Sync and Up-to-date.

Please tell me any solution for this scenario.

Simply, I would like something like this:

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a Stack Overflow topic, it's a "design my system for me" or product selection query. Per the Stack Overflow topic rules your question will probably get closed as off-topic, and frankly you could write a book on this topic and not fully cover it. I suggest seeking expert advice - see https://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/ . (Disclosure, I work for one of the listed companies).

Comment: You'll need to think hard about how "in sync" and how "up to date" they have to be. Because unless you have a magic data teleporter, if the link between data center 1 is and data center 2 is down, the db in data center 2 cannot be up to date with data center 2 and vice versa. So you have to decide whether to shut down services on one side of the network partition, or let the two diverge then sync up when done. That's only one of the topics to discuss. This needs a proper analysis based on your requirements and app, and it's not a small topic.

Comment: You'll either need active/standby with failover, or a multimaster setup. The latter comes with considerable complexities and compromises, do not assume multimaster is the right thing to do just because it's available. (I develop a multimaster DB solution for postgres, so I'm not against multimaster, you just have to work out if it's right for you.) Anyway, that's the most I'll say here, and I suggest you seek consulting assistance or pick up a book on high availability design.

Comment: @CraigRinger Great comments. You are my Hero